# Constructing the UrlFetchApp request to obtain an Access Token from ChinaBrands API

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function getAccessToken() 
{
  var url = "https://gloapi.chinabrands.com/v2/user/login";
  var data = {
    "email": EMAILID,
    "password": PWD,
    "client_id": APIKEY
  }
  var payload = {
    "data": data,
    "signature": Utilities.base64Encode(data + SECRETKEY)
  }

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",                 
    "payload": payload
  };
  var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  Browser.msgBox(json);
}
```

Please see attached documentation API screenshot link below.
I am trying to connect ChinaBrands API using google apps script.
I am getting error which says `"{"status":0,"msg":"Requested info is empty","errcode":10006}"`

See this Image : Documentation API to get AccessToken:

[image: See this Image : Documentation API to get AccessToken]

Comment: Hi Kishan Panchal, where did you find that API documentation? I've been searching for it for ages but no luck so far...

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is a bit misleading. You need to make POST request with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The request data field should be a string with your data in JSON format. I guess depending on language/libraries you use, you might need to URL encode the JSON data before making the request.

The resulting request should look like:

```
POST https://gloapi.chinabrands.com/v2/user/login
...
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

signature=<md5 of string containing data in json + client secret>&data=%7B%22email%22%3A+%22name%40example.com%22%2C+%22password%22%3A+%2222password1%22%2C+%22client_id%22%3A+%1337%22%7D
```

Python 3 example with requests library:

```
url = "https://gloapi.chinabrands.com/v2/user/login"

data = {...}

json_data = json.dumps(data)

signature = md5((json_data + client_secret).encode('utf')).hexdigest()

response = requests.post(url, data={'signature': signature, 'data': json_data})
```